# ListBox vs ItemsControl dynamically loaded controls tabbing order

Tags: wpf, listbox, tab-ordering

I have a question regarding the tab order of dynamically loaded controls in WPF.

I have a ListBox as:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyData,Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

I add a couple of TextBlock-Textbox pair (Name-Value pair) in a stackpanel as ListItem. When I tab, rest all items skipped and I come out of ListBox items.

Solution: However if I add the following to ListBox everything works fine:

```
KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
```

Now if I would have used ItemsControl in place of ListBox, I didnt have to use Local navigation, it works fine OOTB. My ItemsControl looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyData,Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Question: Why these two behaviors are different?

Thanks,
RDV

<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Complete XAML Code<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
<ItemsControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Mydata}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <StackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition/>
                 <ColumnDefinition/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

               <Border Background="LightBlue">
                  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             Text="{Binding Name}"/>
               </Border>
               <TextBox  Grid.Column="1"
                         Text="{Binding Value}"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
             </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          </ItemsControl>
```

Add some data in MyData variable from ViewModel.

Just Change ItemsControl to ListBox to see change in tabbing behaviour. if you are not able to tab through items in ListBox (the issue which I am facing), add to ListBox control:

```
 KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
```

Thanks,
RDV

Comment: ItemsControl OOTB doesn't seem to behave the same as ListBox using TabNavigation="Local", unless I'm missing something? The ListBox allows you to tab through single items, the ItemsControl does not?

Comment: ListBox OOTB does *not* allow tabbing through individual items but ItemsControl does. To enable this capability in ListBox, TabNavigation="Local" is required.

Comment: For me, ItemsControl doesn't allow tabbing through individual items. I'll try it again when I get an opportunity.

Comment: In my case, Itemscontrol/Listbox resides inside a user control which is added to the main window which has many other uswecontrols before and after this one. This user control is given keyboard navigation="continue".

Comment: I don't think you can select items within an ItemsControl by default, I'm probably not replicating the problem correctly.

Comment: No, I cannot select items from ItemsControl (atleast there is no such property to get SelectedItem in viewmodel for ItemsControl), but you can tab through the items. I have added some more code to test the scenario.